# SQL copy data from 2 tables from different databases to 1 new database and keep link to source data

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are using a commercial software that uses a Microsoft SQL Server database to store manufacturer data. Let's call this `DBParts`. In addition we have a table in a separate database that contains supplier data, let's call this `DBsupplier`.

I would like to create a new database (`DBNew`) that meets the following requirements:

- The new database should be a copy of the `DBParts`
- If a record is changed / added / delete to any table in `DBParts`, it should be propogated to `DBNew`
- The `DBParts` contains a table with a column `ordernr`. I want to exchange the value of `ordernr` in `DBnew` with the `supplierordernr` from `DBsupplier`.

I have already realized this by creating a `DBNew` with views of all tables from `DBParts`. I exchanged the ordernr using a JOIN with `DBSupplier`.

This works, but I doubt if this is the best solution looking at performance.

Are there better alternatives? What is the best way to go?

Comment: You could read up on replication here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication 

Are there any issues with extending on the database from the commercial database or is it a requirement to have a replicated version of this database? 
For the parts table you could set up a linked server, but if you already have views working i guess there might not be a need for that? 
The best way to go is to get it all in the same database, or at least on the same server if that is possible (same filesystem for the reads)

Comment: Hi Werner, I am thinking about collecting commercial data from different suppliers in 1 database DBSupplier. The format of each table in this database depends on how the supplier delivers his data. If we have 5 suppliers I would like to create 5 new databases, all based on the master DBParts. Replication is an option, if the replication can change the data in 1 column on the fly. Is that possible?

Comment: No the replication forms a queue for your data to be transfered, you could write triggers for your tables, maybe even a dynamic DDL update/insert trigger to catch all updates and ensure the data is updated on the fly, but it does require some work to get it up and running.